# AxShockwaveFlash.CallFunction() Help (VB 2008)

Tags: vb.net, actionscript, flash, flash-integration

I'm trying to use CallFunction() to call a function inside a flash file, but no matter what I do it throws a HRESULT E_FAIL error. Any clues why? My flash version is 10 if you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HRESULT E_FAIL can be due to passing a wrong XML string to the AxShockwaveFlash.CallFunction's argument, or calling a function that is not registered with the ExternalInterface, but it can also be a result of a runtime-error occuring inside the Flash SWF file.

1. Make sure your are passing a valid XML string as the argument (details on Flash's XML format can be found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7caf.html)). Keep in mind that ActionScript is case-sensitive.
2. Make sure the function you're calling actually works well with the supplied arguments, by testing it from inside the Flash Actionscript code.
3. Make sure your Actionscript function is properly registered with the ExternalInterface. Details of using the ExternalInterface for calling an actionscript function from the SWF's container can be found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ca7.html).
4. If you can't find the cause, please supply us with the relevant code of the vb.net method, the Actionscript function and Actionscript ExternalInterface registration.

Comment: Wrap the functionality with your own "proxy" functionality, and make sure each external function in your proxy is properly registered with the ExternalInterface.

Comment: No, because the contained SWF doesn't expose the functions you wish to trigger. The SWF file is like an object, who's public methods are only defined using the ExternalInterface.

Since flash SWF is not native code but intermediate code, SWF files can be "imported" back to FLA files, enabling you to edit the source code. But if the original publisher of the SWF file applied the "import protection" you're going to have some trouble...